# Adding modules to path for Canopy

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

After a new installation of Canopy on Ubuntu, I wanted to make Canopy aware of my personal toolbox of python modules.  On my system's Python installation, I achieved this by placing a a text file called "custom_paths.pth" with a list of paths to my Python modules inside the location:

```
/usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages/
```

where *X.X* is the python version.

Since Canopy uses a virtual environment, how does one achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Using [How to access Esri ArcPy modules from Enthought Canopy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/59144/26781) as a reference, once can make Canopy's Python interpretor aware of custom modules by placing the *.pth* file that lists the paths of interest inside the following folder:

```
/home/USER/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Where the first part of the path is where you installed Enthought Canopy.

Comment: Another solution is to list any toolbox paths in the PYTHONPATH environment variable. This is the canonical use of PYTHONPATH, as opposed to the risky use of it to point into some other site-packages directory.